# How can I create a random number from a SHA256 Hash?

Tags: php

Good morning,

I have to create a random number from a given 256HASH using a secret key. Everyting is fine, until I have to "convert" the hash into an integer between 0 and 15.000.000 (which is the random number). I have been playing with ord() and bytes but I don't get anything that suits me.

My original idea was to cast the SHA256 string into an integer, and then apply a divisor to obtain the modulus. But I need a random number between a very big range. 0 to 15.000.000 (fifteen million). How would you do it?

Thanks!

Comment: You need `hexdec()` or `base_convert()`, not `ord()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hash i basically a number, just with a base of 16. Having said that, you just have to convert it to an int.

The problem is, when you convert a hash into a int like so:

```
echo intval(hash('sha256','asdf'),16);
```

You will always get 2147483647 for 32-bit systems, which is the maximum value for intval.

My suggestion would be to cut the value of the hash to a few first characters like so

```
 echo intval(substr(hash('sha256','bsbaf'),0,6),16);
```

This is now the seed for the random number, you can get the random by:

```
 $hash = hash('sha256','bsbaf');
 $seed = intval(substr($hash,0,6),16);
 mt_srand($seed);
 echo mt_rand(0,15000000);
```

Note that in some cases, you can have collisions, because you are using only the first 6 chars of the hash, but for most uses this will not be a problem. It's up to you to decide if this is acceptable since I do not know your specific use case.

UPDATE: An alternative is to make modulo from the resulting seed - like so:

```
 $hash = hash('sha256','bsbaf');
 $seed = intval(substr($hash,0,6),16);
 echo $seed % 15000000;
```

Comment: Dear GregPK, I have extracted the 8 first bytes of the string which could theorically generate numbers up to 8000M. I then should apply the modulus to obtain a number between my range. Thank you.

Comment: I am having problems though. When applying intval() to the resulting 8byte string (which is for example "d545730d"), it always returns ZERO! Any clues?

Comment: add the base parameter: intval("d545730d",16);

Comment: Dear Greg, I did. However, received number is not unsigned and any number above 2147483647 is lost, and  2147483647 is returned. Any ideas?

Comment: Updated my answer to your case - 8 chars from the seed is to long, the amount I gave originally (6) is safe and will not overflow the int.

Comment: Dear Greg, I am extracting 8bytes from the string. Like this: mb_strcut($seed, 0, 8); Extracting 6 bytes would to the trick? It seems so! Will it every overflow?

Comment: The maximum value of a 6 characted hexidecimal string is 0xffffff, which is 16777215 and hence will not overflow ever.